# Accesing an instance of Class from another class

Tags: java

Im writing a project using an API .
So overall my program looks like so .

```
public class Programm extends bridge {
Client Eclient = new Client() ;
public static void main(String[] args) {
Programm MyProgramm = new Programm();
MyProgramm.MyMethod();
public void MyMethod(){
 Runnable countdown = new flipper();
 Thread worker = new Thread(countdown);
 worker.start();
}
}
abstract bridge implements API{}
class flipper implements runnable {
public void run(){MyProgramm.Eclient.ApiMethod()}
}
```

Basiclly i need to access the EClient class instance as it would be accesed by MyProgramm instance from class flipper

Comment: Yes; this is very hard to read.

Comment: (1) indentation, (2) java nameing conventions. Both help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2: Make Flipper an inner class

```
public class Program extends bridge {
   Client eClient = new Client() ;
   public void main(String[] args) {...}
   public void myMethod(){...}
   class Flipper implements Runnable {
      public void run(){Program.eClient.apiMethod()}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class flipper implements Runnable {
private ESocket lEClient;
   public flipper (Object pEClient) {
     lEClient = pEClient;
   }
```

And then you call use the constructor like this:

```
public void MyMethod()
 {

   Runnable countdown = new flipper(Eclient);

  Thread worker = new Thread(countdown);
   worker.start();
 }

public void run() {lEClient .Apimethod()}
```